# assignment from incompatible pointer type in linked list (C)

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes, traversal

I am having some problems creating a linked list and also some helper functions that I am trying to make. My code is as follows:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "getNextWord.h"

#define MAX_WORD_SIZE 256

typedef struct{
int counter;
char* key;
struct node* next;
} node;

node* createNode(char* words){
    node* head;
    if(!(head=malloc(sizeof(node)))) return NULL;
    head->key=words;
    head->next=NULL;
    return head;
}

node* addToList(node* head, char* words){
    node* newNode;
    newNode=createNode(words);
    newNode->next = head;
    return newNode;
}

int find(node* head){
    if (head->next != NULL){
        node* next = head->next;

        while(head != NULL){
            if (strcmp(head->key,next->key)==0){
                head->counter++;
                head=head->next;
                return 1;
                }
            else{
                head=head->next;
                }
            }
    }
return 0;
}

void printList(node* head){
    node* pointer = head;
    while (pointer != NULL){
        printf("%s",pointer->key);
        pointer=pointer->next;
        }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    if(argc<2){
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough arguments given\n");
        }

    for(int i=1; i< argc; i++){
        FILE* fd=fopen(argv[i], "r");
        if(fd != NULL){
            char* words;
            node* head = NULL;
            while((words=getNextWord(fd)) != NULL){
                find(head);
                if (find(head) == 0){
                    createNode(words);
                    }
                printList(head);


                fprintf(stdout,"%s\n",words);
                }
            }

        else(printf("No such file exists"));
        fclose(fd);
        }
return 0;
}
```

I looked around on the Internet and it would seem I am following what most people are doing in regards to the linked list. I wasn't getting any errors before, just a bunch of "warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type" in the following functions:

```
addtolist (the line before the return)
find (before return one and the else line)
printlist (the last line in the while loop)
```

I know it's not that great of code, I'm not the best programmer, but just trying to learn. Also, my getnextword does work, but if it's needed for something I can post that too.

Answer (score 5):

Your are mixing up two different "namespaces" the "tag" namespace for `struct` and alike and the identifier namespace for `typedef`. The easiest to get along with this is to forward declare the types you are going to use:

```
typedef struct node node;
```

Then afterwards you can use `node` or `struct node` interchangeably. Even inside

```
struct node {
  // something
  node * next;
};
```

Comment: If your saying that I shouldn't name things node* node then that makes sense. I was naming them node* somethingelse (obviously not exactly that) and that is when I wasn't getting any errors but was still getting the warnings, which ended in a segmentation fault in my first find statement, which now makes sense since ->next is NULL at that point and it should crash. I can change it back over and edit my first post to what I had before.

Comment: Also, a `node*` and a `struct node*` are two different things, unless you make them not two different things as described here.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct tag_node {
    int counter;
    char* key;
    struct tag_node* next;
} node;
```

for starters.

As a side-note, I can't imagine how you `free()` `words` within `main` (careful, it might leak).

edit - I accidentally some styles

Comment: This one gets rid of the warnings that I was getting but not the errors. I thought that you didn't need to have a name after struct if using typdef, just at the end. But then again, I am very new to all this and could easily be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
struct node {
  int counter;
  char* key;
  struct node* next;
};
```

You may need to replace `node` with `struct node` in other places in the code.

Comment: Wouldn't I then have to add "struct" in front of "node" every time? I thought that is what typedef was used for, so you didn't have to write struct every time you wanted some sort of reference to what you were making.

Comment: @Defc0n - Yes, that is true as I said in my last line.  It is a matter of style, some programmers prefer the `typedef` other feel it makes the code harder to read.  It is not a macro so it behaves a little differently than a simply a text replacement.

Comment: yeah, I seemed to have missed that line the first time I read it. In my defense I had only slept about 3 hours. I got rid of the errors I was having, now I just need to deal with the warnings.

Answer (score 0):

multiple issues:

```
int find(node* node){
    node* next = node->next;  // what if next is NULL ?
    while(node != NULL){
        if (strcmp(node->key,next->key)==0){ // if next is NULL this will crash
            node->counter++;
            return 1;
            node=node->next;   // never reached since return 1 above.
            }
        else{
            node=node->next;
            }
    }
return 0;
}
```

....

probably good to rename createlist to createnode since that seems to be the function.

```
node* createList(char* words){
    node* node;
    if(!(node=malloc(sizeof(node)))) return NULL;
    node->key=words;
    node->next=NULL;
    return node;
}
```

the string that comes in 'words' is never stored, you need to create a copy of the words and store it e.g.:

```
node->key = strdup(words);
```

Comment: My getnextword function (that I didn't include) does do a strdup of the words already. Is this one still necessary or would that be allocating memory for the same thing twice? And yes, stupid mistake with returning 1 where I did, not thinking there. Also, for the first error there, I could just add a simple if (node->next != NULL) then do that statement correct?